# Test automation with two-factor authentication

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, two-factor-authentication

I have automatic tests with Selenium and i use visual studio and c#, and this automatic tests have to test a portal where they have to enter email and password, and accessed the platform where he made the general controls of the platform, but they decided to put the authentication to two factors, so I do not know how more to do

Comment: See : https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/basic-http-authentication  There is a c# tab for example of code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: See https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/selenium-testing---how-to-sign-in-to-two-factor-authentication-2joi